# Making videojs progress bar in thicker in height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs in my react application. Currently the default skin in my application has the progress bar very thin in height. I want to have a thicker progress bar. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Add this code after the videojs styles (.css) on your html head or move the code to a css file that will be loaded after:

```
<style>
  .video-js .vjs-progress-holder .vjs-play-progress,
  .video-js .vjs-progress-holder .vjs-load-progress,
  .video-js .vjs-progress-holder .vjs-tooltip-progress-bar,
  .video-js .vjs-progress-holder .vjs-load-progress div {
    height: 0.3em;}
</style>
```

height: 0.3em is the default.
Change the default value for anyone that you wish.
One more thing, you may need to change the .vjs-slider css class too, otherwise your bar may be bigger than the slider.
Check the videojs css code, everything is there.